# Bootstrap dropdowns want to force accordion style always

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working from this [tutorial](http://www.jonathanbriehl.com/2014/01/17/vertical-menu-for-bootstrap-3/) for side navigation with bootstrap.

So far my side nav looks great, however I want to force the drop downs to be the accordion style they are when the are in the mobile (collapsed) menu, all the time.

In other words I never want me dropdowns to "pop-over" other content I want them to expand.

So I want this effect always:

[image]

Even when the menu is at the side like this:

[image]

Anyone know how to achieve this???

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to adjust the given CSS some...

```
/* make sidebar nav vertical */ 
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar-nav .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    padding: 0;
    max-height: none;
}
.sidebar-nav .navbar ul {
    float: none;
}
.sidebar-nav .navbar ul:not {
    display: block;
}
.sidebar-nav .navbar li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
}
.sidebar-nav .navbar li a {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}
}
```

As you can see, the CSS changes at a width of 768px. Change that value to whatever size screens you wish to target, and you'll get the result you're after.

Comment: I know what I mean though is I want it at the side until ``768px`` but I want the dropdowns to expand in the accordion style as opposed to pop over then at ``768px`` I want it to switch to collapsed.

Comment: Have you tried applying the same CSS outside of the media query?

Comment: This might be of interest to you... it looks like what you're after... http://www.bootply.com/uBoT3zP1P2

Comment: Yeah I did find that, basically how it is I like and I like that it has been integrated as a nav, I just want the dropdown to be styled as mobile all the time.